# Custom directive not displaying withing a ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a custom dircetive "3-test-directive" which I want to call to display a text. When I use this directive in the page partial-home.html, it does not diaplay me with any text from the directive(it seems the directive did not work).

When I use the same code <3-test-directive/> inside of index.htm, the directive is correctly parsed. Why did not the one with the partial-home.html did not work and how can I fix this ?

Demo for this code : https://plnkr.co/edit/wy5gkUlXmbRpyrdqwHwd?p=preview

index.html

```
    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="routerApp">

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <p>A tutorial by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a></p>
    <p>View the tutorial: <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router" target="_blank">AngularJS Routing using UI-Router</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // nested list with custom controller
        .state('home.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
            }
        })

        // nested list with just some random string data
        .state('home.paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },
                'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },
                'columnTwo@about': { 
                    templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
                    controller: 'scotchController'
                }
            }

        });

});

routerApp.controller('scotchController', function($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'test';

    $scope.scotches = [
        {
            name: 'Macallan 12',
            price: 50
        },
        {
            name: 'Chivas Regal Royal Salute',
            price: 10000
        },
        {
            name: 'Glenfiddich 1937',
            price: 20000
        }
    ];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include scripts in templates...they get stripped out.

Just register the directive in your js file

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router'])


.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict:'E',
        template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
    };
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/I51sL4xtTQDg5izXdYJW?p=preview)**</kbd>